# Server for arduino

Tags: java, html, arduino

I am trying to set up a server to receive data from arduinos and display the data on a website. I can handle the arduino client side but...

I purchased a website through hostgator and am completely lost on how to use a service such as that to get what I want. Using an arduino as a server, or using a private or lab server is not an option.

I could do it in java, but the service would won’t support java unless I spend more money for a dedicated server and I’m not willing to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you set on using an Arduino?

If your aim is to stream data directly to a web server, there are plenty of better options out there with built in wifi and all the libraries you could dream of.

I suggest a nodeMCU, or if you are set on an arduino, you will need an ethernet shield.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The arduinos are the clients. I am trying to figure out how to make a server for them, that is not physically mine so I don’t have to worry about physical maintenance, just the coding aspect. The end goal is server/website from which the arduino data can be read, downloaded, etc

Comment: If you want your arduinos as clients, you'll still need an Ethernet shield or similar, otherwise they will have no way of talking to the server. Unless of course they are permanently connected to a PC and the serial data from the arduinos uploaded to the server from there?